# Books Won't Display for Reader App Exercise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, reader

I'm trying to get books to display based on the [assignment](http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/4/reader/README.html) above but can't figure out what is wrong for the life of me.

I built the service and modified the controller and view pages to the point where I believe they should display the books in the view, but I'm just seeing a blank page.

I feel like I am probably not retrieving the data properly and accessing it in the view/html.

Any ideas? [Link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b3ckm4n/9nn5h3L9/).

### Index.html

```
<body ng-app="ReaderApp">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="container">
        Reader
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
      <div class="container">

        <div ng-view></div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modules -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script src="js/controllers/BookshelfController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/BookController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/ChapterController.js"></script>

    <!-- Services -->
    <script src="js/services/books.js"></script>

  </body>
```

---

### js/apps.js

```
var app = angular.module('ReaderApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/books', {
        controller: 'BookshelfController',
        templateUrl: 'views/bookshelf.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirecTo: '/books'
    });
});
```

---

### js/services/books.js

```
app.factory('books', ['$http', function($http) {
    return $http.get('https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp4/books-api/books.json')
        .success(function(data) {
            return data;
        })
        .error(function(err) {
            return err;
        });
}]);
```

---

### js/controllers/BookshelfController

```
app.controller('BookshelfController', ['$scope', 'books', function($scope, books) {
    books.success(function(data) {
        $scope.myBooks = data;
    });
}]);
```

---

### js/views/bookshelf.html

```
<div class="bookshelf row">
  <!-- 
  TODO: Loop through myBooks and display each one with this HTML
  <div class="book col-md-3">
    <a href="#/books/{{$index}}">
      TODO: Add the book's cover here
      <h3 class="title">  </h3>
      <p class="author">  </p>
    </a>
  </div>
  -->
  <div class="book col-md-3" ng-repeat="book in myBooks">
      <a href="#/books/{{$index}}">
        <img ng-src="{{ book.cover }}">
        <h3 class="title">{{ book.title }}</h3>
        <p class="author">by {{ book.author }}</p>
      </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please repost this using jsFiddle. Use this preconfigured fiddle as your basis: http://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/HB7LU/

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I updated the question with a link to jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the same trouble and my problem was in the router. Try adding array brackets ( **[ ]** ) and the *'$routeProvider'* string in your config method (*app.js*) like this:

```js
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  // Normal router stuff goes here
}]);
```

Coming from Ember, the syntax is a little weird so I've been using [this tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07) as reference when I get stuck.